# Mediawiki last edited pages

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have a big media wiki with many pages, which is quite well structured and maintained by many people.

However, I would need some gadget or functionality to show the latest changes on the main page.

E.g.: Name of the changed page, ordered by it's date - 20 rows in a list ..

Maybe not every small saving of edited text but in general the last page which was edited.

Is there some way to achieve this? It would be quite helpful for the users to see if something was changed recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transclude from the `Special:Recentchanges` or if you want to embed the changes somewhere, add the `{{Special:RecentChanges/20}}` code in your page.